# Converting a string to a procedure

Tags: string, lambda, scheme

I'm creating a program that allow a user introduce a lambda function only writing it in the interface writing box like this:

```
(lambda (p q) (and (not p) q))
```

This is the result "(lambda (p q) (and (not p) q))" because scheme convert it to a string instead of a procedure that can be evaluated.

How can i convert this string into a procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scheme, the `eval` function only operates on lists of symbols, so this would work fine:

```
(eval '(+ 1 2))
```

But this would give an error:

```
(eval "(+ 1 2)")
```

To convert a string from the UI into a list of symbols (AKA an S-expression), you'll need to call the `read` function. Regularly, `read` only operates on "ports" (file stream), so you'll need to convert your string into an input port before it's usable with `read`:

```
(define (read-string text)
  (read
    (open-input-string text)))
```

All that's left is to evaluate the string, and call the lambda that you get as a result:

```
(define (call-string text-lambda . args)
  (apply
    (eval (read-string text-lambda))
    args))
```

Here's how you can now calculate the number 3:

```
(call-string "(lambda (a b) (+ a b))" 1 2)
```

You find the APIs for `read` and `open-input-string` at the [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.6.2) and [SRFI](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-6/srfi-6.html) websites.